# Alternatives to Pickel and CSV for file manipulation in python

Tags: python, csv

So i have been given a task to develop an employee database and store all information in a CSV file. After adding information i need usable options for removing, editing and searching said data. Its a grey area on what I can and can't import so if there's a method using no porting that would be perfect. Basically, anything just using read() and write().

However, no matter what I do I can't find help online on how to actually pull this specific data in a usable format. Below is how I'm adding it to the CSV file, but no matter what I try I end up wiping the file or just getting errors when I attempt a removal process. Hopefully, whenever I can find a way to pull this data, the edit and search functions will be just a case of logic.

(My Add Function)

```
def add_employee(): #THIS WORKS
    EmployeeID = int(input("Please enter the employee ID here "))
    EmployeeName = input("Please enter the name here ")
    EmployeeDep = input("Please enter the department here ")
    EmployeeDes = input("Please enter the designation here ")
    EmployeeStartDate = input("Please enter the start date here in format of DD-MM-YYYY ")
    EmployeeStatus = input("Please enter the status here ")

    with open('database.csv', "a") as f:
        employee_add = ""
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeID
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeName
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeDep
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeDes
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeStartDate
        employee_add += "%s," % EmployeeStatus
        employee_add += "\n"
        f.write(employee_add)
        print("Added correctly")
        continue_or_quit()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommed using pandas:

`import pandas as pd`

Load in your csv file to a dataframe object:
`employee_df = pd.read_csv("employee_info.csv")`

You can add new rows:

```
name = "name"    
password = "password"
email = "email@domain.com"
# depends on your columns, and the order of them!
employee_df.loc[df.index.max()+1] = [name, password, email]
```

And then export it to csv again:
`employee_df.to_csv("employee_info.csv", index=False)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill give it a go but i'm not 100% sure im allowed any import functions, its a bit of a grey area. Do you know of alternatives?

Comment: Not allowed any? Yes, pandas is an external module you need to install, although it may be included in your python setup already. Unless it's a homework, restricting you to not using external modules, try to get permission from whoever in charge, because one of the great things about python is the modules. If your python setup doesn't have network access, there are ways to install modules 'offline' (after saving the necessary files locally first)

Comment: Myself and others on the course have tried getting the permission of CSV, Pickle and other methods but so far we have been rejected on all attempts so we are just going by the idea nothing can be imported and that we are restricted to barebones python.

Comment: Huh well the 'csv' module itself is built in, and if you really aren't allowed to use that, then I guess the person in charge is treating this more of a general programming course than anything python specific...

So, if you are are not allowed to use 'csv', I would read the file one line at a time, loads each line's columns into a dict/object, and have an array of these dicts.

When you are done adding dicts (users) etc, parse the dicts and save them back to a csv file.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go and see how it is, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I actually quite like working with csv's in python using just regular formatting.

things like:

```
rows = content.split("\n") # get the rows (content in this example would be result of .read()

for row in rows:
    values = row.split(",") # get row values
```

To add a row as per your example you can use something like:

```
row = "{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, EmployeeDep, EmployeeDes, EmployeeStartDate, EmployeeStatus)

with open(output, "a") as f:
    f.write(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, do you have any suggestions on how id repeat this for multiple record sets at once?

Comment: just stick it in a for loop